# Overridding ComponentModel attributes (ie, DisplayName) doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, system.componentmodel

I have two classes:

```
public class DocumentViewModel
{
    public virtual string DocumentNumber { get; set; }
}

public class PurchaseOrderViewModel : DocumentViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("PO Number")]
    public override string DocumentNumber { get; set; }
}
```

And a view:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Onyx.Web.Models.PurchaseOrderViewModel>" %>

<strong><%: Html.LabelFor(i => i.DocumentNumber) %>:</strong> <%: Model.DocumentNumber %>
```

I expect that to render

```
<strong>PO Number:</strong> PO-12345
```

but it actually renders

```
<strong>DocumentNumber:</strong> PO-12345
```

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: I looked at the possible duplicate, but there was no resolution, plus it was asked back in March.  I was hoping things may have changed.

Comment: I tried the cast, no such luck :( Also, I can understand what's happening in the other question, since their base model has an attribute.  In my example, only the child has the attribute assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a solution to my own problem.  It's not perfect, but it's alright.

Since these are just ViewModels, there's not logic in them.  So, I changed `class DocumentViewModel` to `interface IDocumentViewModel` and, *voilà*, problem solved.

I'd still like to get this working for inheriting classes, but that's more my stubbornness than any business case.